# RecyclerView empty when click icon back in toolbar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

I need set back icon in my **`toolbar`**. I created my toolbar using **`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`** and for back using this code first set `onClick` to my back icon by this code:

```
     ImageView backIcon = findViewById(R.id.back_icon);
    backIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(CreateNewItem.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

and add this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

it's work and back to activity but my problem it's when using back icon and back to activity see `recyclerView` is empty and `activity` not have data. what is my problem?

Comment: you have to write the logic to print show list data in onResume() method of the activity

Answer (score 1):

If You are using **`Toolbar`** then no need to set custom back icon, you have to just override this method

```
@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
    } 
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
}
```

and enable **`Toolbar`**:

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Happy coding!!